# How can I limit the picked files as a maximus number which user picking using File Picker

Tags: flutter, image, file, dart, filepicker

***Flutter , Dart***

I am using `file_picker` with `allowMultiple: true` as parameter , but couldn't find a parameter for limiting the number of maximum files which user gonna pick from gallery

Is this possible?, if not How can I do it ?

great regards

```
 final  result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true ,  type: FileType.custom , allowedExtensions: ['jpg','png','mp4'], );
```

Comment: I think there is now such parameter right now to tell the max file to select. till this date. you may can limit the number of files from the list after the user select "n" files.

Comment: thanks Alan , since it inappropriate to make user select first then limit , so i decided to use photo_manager its more better than file picker anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found another package that can limit the number of maximum files to pick from gallery. The limit can be set using param `maxImages` https://pub.dev/packages/multi_image_picker2.

```
final pickedAssets = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
  maxImages: 30,
);
```

Or this package, using param `maxAssets` https://pub.dev/packages/wechat_assets_picker

```
final pickedAssets = await AssetPicker.pickAssets(
  context,
  pickerConfig: AssetPickerConfig(
    maxAssets: 30,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).